# CQRS and email notification

Tags: email, domain-driven-design, notifications, cqrs

Reading up on CQRS there is a lot of talk of email notification - i'm wondering where to get the data from. Imagine a senario where one user invites other users to an event.  To inform a user that he has been invited to an event, he is sent an email.

The concrete steps might go like this:

1. A `CreateEvent` command with an associated collection of users to invite, is received by the server.
2. A new `Meeting` aggregate is created and a method `InviteUser` is called for each user that is to be invited.
3. Each time a user is invited to an event, a domain event `UserWasInvitedToEvent` is raised.
4. An email notification sender picks up the domain event and sends out the notification email.

Now my question is this: Where do I go for information to include in the email?

Say I want to include a description of the event as well as the user's name. Since this is CQRS I can't get it thru my domain model; All the properties of the domain objects are private! Should I then query the read side? Or maybe move email notification to a different service entirely?

Answer (score 6):

In CQRS, you're separating the command from the query side.  You will always want to go to the query side in order to get data for a given event handler.  The write database is going to be a separate database that contains the data necessary for building up your domain objects and will not be optimized for reads, but for writes.

1. The domain should register and send an `EventCreated` event to the event handlers / processors.  This could be raised from the constructor of the `Meeting` aggregate.
2. The event processing component would pick up the `EventCreated` event, and update the query database with the data contained in the event (ie, the Id of the event and its name).
3. The domain could register and send a `UserWasInvitedToEvent` event to the event processors.
4. The event processors would pick up the `UserWasInvitedToEvent` and update the query store with any reporting data necessary.
5. Another event processing component would also pick up the `UserWasInvitedToEvent` event.  This process could have access to the query database and pull back all of the data necessary for sending the email.

The query database is nothing more than a reporting database, so you could even have a specific table that stores all of the data required for the email in one place.

In order to orchestrate several different events into a single handler (assuming the events might be processed in a different order at different times), you could utilize the concept of a [Saga](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/04/20/saga-persistence-and-event-driven-architectures/) in your messaging bus.  NServiceBus is an example of a messaging bus that [supports Saga's](http://blogs.planbsoftware.co.nz/?p=247).  See this StackOverflow question as well: [NServiceBus Delayed Message Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311331/nservicebus-delayed-message-processing).

Comment: It's incredible how much difference a single word can make. I meant to say query the READ side ofcours! I am aware of the basics of CQRS :) 

Anyways, what you are saying is you would go to the query store for the data to include in the email?

I can see how this could pose a problem, as the query store might not nessesery be up to date, when the UserWasInvitedToEvent event arrives.

One possible solution could be a component / service that would listen for new meetings, user and invitations and store that data, so it could send out invitations?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was getting at.  There are such things as Saga's in certain messaging frameworks such as NServiceBus that allow you to orchestrate several event handlers that do not necessarily arrive in the same order each time.  You may want to look into that as well.  These act as a workflow of sorts that would allow you to wait on all pertinent information before performing some action.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - sorry for not getting back to this a long time ago. I like what you decribe, but I found that I prefer a slightly different approach: enriching the event.

Comment: @t0PPy Please post a new answer here detailing your preferred solution and mark it as your approved answer. SO is all about being able to find answers to questions later on as well. Some one who finds this question later might miss out on the info about enriching the events, which IMHO is a pretty important concept in CQRS. More info to the masses!

Comment: I know this is late to the party, but the lights are still on so here it goes: need some elaboration on point 5: _Another event processing component_, where, in the read-side? _could have access to the query database_, you mean the projected store/database in the read-side?